# The expressiveness of fold(r)?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, fold

I am working on kind of blog-post/paper regarding fold. Mostly I stick to `fold : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` signature, however fold-left might work as well.

What I need is as many examples as possible, where fold used to implement well-known and commonly used bits like:

`sum = foldr (+) 0`

`product = foldr (*) 1`

`any = foldr (||) False`

`all = foldr (&&) True`

`(++ ys) = foldr (:) ys`

`length = foldr (\_ n -> n + 1) 0`

`reverse = foldr (\x xs -> xs ++ [x]) []`

`map f = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) []`

`filter p = foldr (\x xs -> if p x then x : xs else xs) []`

`concat = foldr (++) []`

`compose = foldr (.) id`

All the examples above are written and tested in Haskell, however I can accept any language, including OO-ones.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**:

`foldl f a xs = foldr (\x k a -> k (f a x)) id xs a`

`factorial n = foldr (*) 1 [1..n]`

Comment: factorial n = fold (*) 1 [1..n]

Comment: `min [] = error "min called on an empty list"`
`min (a:as) = foldr (\x y -> if x < y then x else y) ??? as`

Comment: @NikolayLebedev, makes sense to proceed on Maybe rather than throwing exception. However, good examples, thanks. Will update OP to include those.

Comment: [`Data.Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) has many examples of useful methods (`length`, `elem`, `null`, …) and interesting instances (`Maybe`?).

Comment: `foldl f a xs = foldr (\x k a -> k (f a x)) id xs a`

Comment: @AaditMShah, huh, nice one. BTW, is this one space-leak dangerous as well?

Comment: good question but not really one for SO, unfortunately

Comment: @naomik which place would be better?

Comment: head, last, take, takeWhile, takeUntil,
 [foldlWhile](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative), ... group, ... span,  break, spans, breaks, ... splitAt, ... inits, tails, ... (scanl ?)

Comment: This might interest you: [A Million Ways to Fold (in JS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZSoPZUoR58)